# Two approaches to adding freelance/contract work to resume

Tags: resume, freelancing

**Approach A**

- Title, *Company A*
- **Freelance + Title, *Company B***
- Title, *Company C*
- **Freelance + Title, *Company D***
- Title, Intern, *Company E*

**Approach B**

- Title, *Company A*
- Title, *Company B*
- **Title, *Self***
- Title, Intern, *Company D*

In approach B, you would list all freelance/contract work you did under the "Title, Self" experience. For example:

- Company A

  - Project 1
  - Project 2
- Company B

  - Project 1

**Question** Which of these two approaches is better? And why?

Comment: Is this intended to be a chronological resume?  If so, then A would be more accurate I'd think.

Comment: Unless you suddenly want to go permanent, it makes no difference. After decades of contracting, I have never actual stated that I was contracting - it simply would not have occurred to me to do so. It certainly hasn't prevented me from landing more contacts. Switching to perm might be different.

Answer (score 5):

These days, whether you're freelance or employee is not viewed as material.  If you're an employee, you have 'Title - Company A'.  If you're freelancing you have 'Title - Company B (Contractor)'. The working arrangement should be at the end, not at the beginning.

Comment: That's the way I do it, and I've been repeatedly complimented on my resume.

Comment: I see two problems: 1. Some freelance work is done without a contract, so the term contractor might be misleading. 2. Listing freelance projects separately increases the length of the resume.

Comment: @melhosseiny - 'contracts' don't have to be written.  You are actually agreeing to a contract simply by pumping gas in your car and then paying.  If someone agrees to a job at a rate or a price it's a 'contract', particularly at the point where money changes hands. 'Small' projects should be rolled into a paragraph.  If you work on 'contract' on a 3 year project it's pretty much equivalent to full time employment.

Comment: Elegant solution, would this how you would also describe developer freelancing too?  Example, like Software Engineer (contracted) for developing a cloud service or Mobile Developer (contracted) for developing an iphone app instead of iPhone App Freelance